# Bootstrap grid inside list items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to put Bootstrap 3 `row`s and `col-*`s inside my numbered list. More specifically I have a form which allows adding multiple addresses. Each address consists of form fields (street, city, etc.). These fields aligned in `col-*`s, because I need to control their appearance for different screen sizes.

This is what I expect for each list entry:

[image]

Instead the second list inidices are at unexpected positions:

https://jsfiddle.net/7h99oyLc/1/

Comment: The problem is the 2nd li entry and the fields have to be on the Same line as the list index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Variant 2. `content: counter(list)`

I've used the `:before` pseudo-element with the `counter` property instead of `<ol><li></li></ol>`.

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/gfdxdnje/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.container-list {
  counter-reset: list;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.container-list > .row {
  margin-top: 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.container-list > .row:before {
  counter-increment: list;
  content: counter(list) ".";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
}

.container-list input {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-list">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input placeholder="field 1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input placeholder="field 2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input placeholder="field 3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <input placeholder="field 4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <input placeholder="field 5">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input placeholder="field 1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input placeholder="field 2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input placeholder="field 3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <input placeholder="field 4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <input placeholder="field 5">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Variant 1. `float: right;`

http://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/pwtkcusy/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

li {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
li .row {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
li .row input {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input placeholder="field 1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input placeholder="field 2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input placeholder="field 3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <input placeholder="field 4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <input placeholder="field 5">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input placeholder="field 1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input placeholder="field 2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input placeholder="field 3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <input placeholder="field 4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <input placeholder="field 5">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: While this looks correct, it's invalid HTML. `div` is not allowed inside `ol`

Comment: @fishbone I've changed my first solution, And I've added new one. I've used the `:before` pseudo-element with the `counter` property instead of `<ol><li></li></ol>`. Please check the result.

Comment: This looks good. I will check it in a few days when I work on that project again